# set width of div relative to another div text like table td

Tags: css, html

Check the first image.

I have set the `div` just displays in images.

![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZVbu.png

the html is :

```
<div id="div_pro_qty_condi_168">
               <label>Loyalty Cards :</label> 
               <input type="text" name="pro_qty_condi[168]" class="text_box_medium">
         </div>
         <div id="div_pro_qty_condi_1">
             <label>Premium Business Cards :</label> 
             <input type="text" name="pro_qty_condi[1]" class="text_box_medium">
         </div>
.         
.
.
.
        <div id="div_pro_qty_condi_135">
            <label>Fearless Drawstring Bag :</label> 
             <input type="text" name="pro_qty_condi[135]" class="text_box_medium">
        </div>
```

How can I set label to maximum size related to  other biggest div like if I use `table` instead of `div` it auto set the `<td>` width as label text, but how can I set it with `div`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/R38wT/)**

```
label{
      display:inline-block;
     width:35%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There maybe better ways but off the top of my head you could do sometime like this.

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="div_pro_qty_condi_168">
        <div>
            <label>Loyalty Cards :</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="pro_qty_condi[168]" class="text_box_medium" />
    </div>
    <div id="div_pro_qty_condi_1">
        <div>
            <label>Premium Business Cards :</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="pro_qty_condi[1]" class="text_box_medium" />
    </div>
    <div id="div_pro_qty_condi_135">
        <div>
            <label>Fearless Drawstring Bag :</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="pro_qty_condi[135]" class="text_box_medium" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
div {
    display: table;
}
div div {
    display: table-row;
}
div div div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ZDN4H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){
    var _nLen = $('label').length;
    var _nMax = $("label:eq(0)").width();
    for(var i=0; i<_nLen;i++) {
        var _nTemp=0;
        _nTemp = $("label:eq("+i+")").width();
        if(_nTemp>=_nMax) {
            _nMax = _nTemp;
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<_nLen;i++) {
        $("label:eq("+i+")").css('display','inline-block');
        $("label:eq("+i+")").css('width',(_nMax+'px'));
    }
});
```